# MySQL - PHP geolocation: how to know to which area a gps location belongs

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geolocation, openstreetmap

I have a location table and a location GPS points table such as

```
location:
id  name
1   New York
2   Ohio
```

location_gps_coordinate (numbers make no sense, just an example)

```
location_id order lat         long
1           1     41.622302   2.06703
1           2     42.722302   2.04703
1           3     42.822302   2.08703
2           1     38.622302   2.01703
2           2     39.722302   2.02703
2           3     40.822302   2.03703
```

So this coordinates draw an area over the map. My question is, given a GPS location (with lat and long) is there any way to know if those coordinates belong to any of the locations in the database? Is there any way to search that directly with MySQL or maybe with PHP or any other language?

Comment: Logically. No. Next.

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps API? I would assume you do as you said your coords "draw an area over the map". If yes then how are you drawing it? Your question is unclear.

Comment: hi, no this is not for google maps api. I just have the coordinates of an area and I want to know if a certain location belongs to that area

Answer (score 0):

The solution came up using the spatial functions and field types in mysql:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html